# JAVA - The declared package <package name> does not match the expected package "" in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

I know this question asked a lot and i read most answer but non of them solved my problem.

I'm kinda new at java but i'm using vscode over than a year. I never come across this kinda problem on other languages, libraries, frameworks.

When i open vscode, a couple seconds later, all my java source code files turns red and the error is

`The declared package <package name> does not match the expected package ""`

but jokes on me **i dont have any packages on those files**. when i open the source code files, some of them stays same, others turn normal?

[image]

I saw the extensions can cause this problem, like Java Language Support - by George Fraser
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac

I uninstall that, only microsoft's and red hat's extensions left. I have reloaded window a couple hundred times, close folder ets. I have no idea what is going on, please help.

Comment: Please add code always as text not as image

Comment: i was not trying to show the code, so i didnt

Answer (score 1):

Your class is located in the package (folder) `week3.lesson`.

So you have to add the package declaration:

```
package week3.lesson
```

to the class.

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character and be camelCase not snake_case.
In your case your class should be named:`DrawCards`

Comment: i never heard that should add the folder name to the source code and it wasn't a problem until a few weeks ago. So i thought the problem wasnt that

Comment: *I  never heard that should add the folder name to the source code* not the folder name. The package name!! The folder names are separated by `/` or \. The package name by `.`

Comment: @RukiyeArıcan If you never heard about packages I would recommend reading [The Java™ Tutorials  - Lesson: Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Comment: @Jens i dont use any packages in those files. Also if I were using a package and hadn't included it in the code, the program wouldn't have worked. all of these files are compiled and runs perfectly. I just receive this error

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS i know about packages a little, i'm still learning phase. thank you for documentation

Answer (score 1):

- Hover the mouse over the red wavy line to view error messages.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and restart vscode.

*If you can run the code normally, you can ignore the warning.*

Comment: - I did Clean Java Language Server Workspace before, and tried again couple minutes ago. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: - It runs normally but if i'm doing something wrong, i want to fix it. Also I don't wanna mix up this error and serious errors in the future.

- In the other answer they said i should add package declaration but i don't use any package in those files, and it wasn't a problem until a few weeks ago. 

- The suggestion package up here was week3.lesson. Then I got really confused because they are just packageless folder names. 

- Lastly when i open the red source code files, some of them stays same, others turn normal. 

- I hope i didn't be pain in the ash, i just really need help :d

Comment: Although they are just normal folder structures, they are recognized as packages in vscode.

Comment: hmm, so should i always add folder names as packages like folder.inside_folder . I never heard this until yesterday and i still dont understand the logic, thank you by the way

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)